# How can I only allow the mouse to hover over two elements?

Tags: javascript, css

When you hover over a green highlight, a div of colors will appear. This will allow you to change the color of the highlight. By the way, the SO Editor is making the offset measure incorrect for the `#change_color` div. **How can I make it where, unless the mouse is over `.green_mark` or `#change_color`, `#change_color` has its visibility hidden?**

```js
$(".green_mark").mouseover(function() {
    var offsets = $(this).offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var new_top = top - 10;
    var left = offsets.left;
    var new_left = left - 10;
    $("#change_color").css("visibility","visible");
    $('#change_color').css({
      'top':new_top+'px',
      'left':new_left+'px'
    });
 });
```

```css
#change_color { 
    position:absolute;
    border:grey solid 1px;
    background: #373737;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
    -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
    -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                 not supported by any browser */
    visibility: hidden;
}

.blue_mark {
  background: #AAF6FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red_mark {
  background: #FF9B9F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green_mark {
  background: #D6FFAA;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow_mark {
  background: #FFF8AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orange_mark {
  background: #FFBF98;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.purple_mark {
  background: #D7D5FC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxes, .boxes2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

#blue_box2 {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}

#green_box2 {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}

#orange_box2 {
  background: #FFBF98;
}

#purple_box2 {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}

#red_box2 {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}

#yellow_box2 {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>
    Lore
<span class="orange_mark">
    m ipsum dolor sit amet, iisque scripserit nec at, an case ponderum mea, delectus volupt
</span>
aria in quo. Te aliquid ce
<span class="red_mark">
    teros legendos has. Veritus assueverit intelleg
</span>
eba
<span class="orange_mark">
    t id per
</span>
, eos cu vero pri
<span class="green_mark">
    mis philo
</span>
sophia, no nec blandit propriae
<span class="green_mark">
    . Mei stet ferri aperiri eu. Mucius deserunt sensibus eum id.
    Ut cas
</span>
e nominavi pro, 
<span class="yellow_mark">
    dico reprimique suscipiantur in per. Cu vocibus ceteros sententiae mel.         Nam te diam ornatus, mei sonet volutpat facilisis ut. Minim mazim    persequeri                
</span>
s sed id, mei et animal equidem, clita atomorum at has. 
<span class="green_mark">
    Ut noluisse placerat suscipiantur mel
</span>
, cu pri mundi dicunt 
<span class="green_mark">
    praesent. Ignota dicunt vulputate ad vim, 
</span>
populo option aperiri 
<span class="orange_mark">
    me
</span>
<span class="purple_mark">
    l in. Has cu essent eirmod malorum, nisl electram pri et.

In legimus posidonium his, aeque possit platonem vel ne, nam ad meis nemore delenit. Cu discere legimus eam. Eum eius nostro ad, pro solet semper per
</span>
<span class="orange_mark">
    fe
</span>
cto ne, et eros dicam tantas pro. Ex malorum debitis cotidieque pro. Vel in legendos elaboraret conclusionemque, mutat moderatius cotidieque cu usu, mel copiosae assueverit ne. Odio imperdiet eos in, cum sint porro splendide ne, tritani aliquam eum ne.

Mel feugiat recusabo platonem ei, sea cu numquam constituam. Ne tempor postea vim. Ad volumus accumsan apeirian has. At ius aliquid convenire, id est aliquip vivendo accusam.

Solum scaevola ius ut, cum no mutat sadipscing. Mei te dico dolor scaevola, cu veri dictas sit, an per nullam oblique. Ex sit sale quidam reprehendunt, diam velit lucilius nam ne, mnesarchum efficiendi his ut. Nec vivendo mediocrem delicatissimi id, ad debet maiorum qui. No qui latine dolorum corpora, diam cetero insolens in cum.
</span>

<div id='change_color'>
  <div id='blue_box2' class='boxes2' title='Blue'></div>
  <div id='green_box2' class='boxes2' title='Green'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box2' class='boxes2' title='Yellow'></div>
  <div id='orange_box2' class='boxes2' title='Orange'></div>
  <div id='purple_box2' class='boxes2' title='Purple'></div>
  <div id='red_box2' class='boxes2' title='Red'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
var colorPickerHovered = false;
var timer;

$(".green_mark").mouseenter(function() {
        if(timer){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    var offsets = $(this).offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var new_top = top - 10;
    var left = offsets.left;
    var new_left = left - 10;
  $("#change_color").css("visibility","visible");
    $('#change_color').css({
  'top':new_top+'px',
  'left':new_left+'px'
    });
 });

$(".green_mark").mouseleave(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if(!colorPickerHovered){
      $("#change_color").css("visibility","hidden");
  }
  }, 250)
})

$("#change_color").mouseenter(function(){
    colorPickerHovered = true;
})

$("#change_color").mouseleave(function(){
    colorPickerHovered = false;
  $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
})
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gqt19vgz/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the mouseout event:

```
$(".green_mark").mouseout(function() {
$("#change_color").css("visibility","hidden");});
```

If you mouseout from the green to get to the color div, it will go wrong though, so make sure the position error is fixed so you never leave the green to go over the color div (so the color div is close by enough); you could render the color div at the mouse position to fix that part too.